# Flutter multiselection searchable dropdown with selected item added to field as chip

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

is there a way to have an inputtextfield with dropdown list, and once item in selected dropdown field selected, add the selected item to textinputfield as image below? I have tried dropdown_search package, it does not meet my requirement as the search bar is in the dropdown list and the list of item in drop down has checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package

```
flutter pub add textfield_tags
```

Comment: Please don't just recommend a library without any information about what the library is or how, specifically, it can be used to solve this specific problem.